# Foreign key property not valid? (Entity framework code first)

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I am using entity framework code first and added a class that has a list of classes of which the classes also have to have another list of classes but when I try to do an update to the database through migrations I get this:

The ForeignKeyAttribute on property 'SubscaleStatistics' on type SubscaleScore' is not valid. The foreign key name 'SubscaleStatisticsId' was not found on the dependent type 'SubscaleScore'. The Name value should be a comma separated list of foreign key property names.

Here's what my classes look like:

```
public class ExamStatistics : StatisticsData
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int TestId { get; set; }
    public IList<SubscaleStatistics> Subscales { get; set; }
}
```

---

```
public class SubscaleStatistics
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int SubscaleStatisticsId { get; set; }
    public int TestId { get; set; }
    public int SubscaleNumber { get; set; }
    public int ExamStatisticsId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ExamStatisticsId")]
    public virtual ExamStatistics ExamStatistics { get; set; }

    public IList<SubscaleScore> SubscaleScores { get; set; }
}
```

---

```
public class SubscaleScore
{
    public int TestId { get; set; }
    public int Subscale { get; set; }
    public double Score { get; set; }
    public int SubscaleId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("SubscaleStatisticsId")]
    public virtual SubscaleStatistics SubscaleStatistics { get; set; }

}
```

What am I doing wrong here? Or do I need to provide more information to get what's wrong?

Comment: Did you try adding `SubscaleStatisticsId` property to `SubscaleScore` class as error states?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add a foreign key property to SubscaleScore.

```
public int SubscaleStatisticsId { get; set; }
```

see here for tutorial: [foreign keys](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/foreignkey-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

the foreignkey must be a id not the object

try something like this:

```
public class SubscaleScore
{
    public int TestId { get; set; }
    public int Subscale { get; set; }
    public double Score { get; set; }
    public int SubscaleId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("SubscaleStatisticsId")]
    public int SubscaleStatisticsId { get; set; }

    public virtual SubscaleStatistics SubscaleStatistics { get; set; }

}
```

do the same for all classes with foreignkey